# Laravel Error: Please provide a valid cache path

Tags: php, laravel

I cloned a Laravel 5.2 project.

When I execute composer install, I got the error:

```
  [InvalidArgumentException]
  Please provide a valid cache path.
```

Theses folders are exists:

```
storage/app
storage/framework
storage/logs

bootstrap/cache
```

and its all 777.

How can i fixed this error!

Comment: They only need to be writable by your nginx/apache process user. 777 isn't recommended.

Comment: Thanks .  I changed its onwer to nginx user .

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I fixed it.

Create these folders under storage/framework:

```
sessions
views
cache
```

And also you can use this command to install:

```
sudo composer install
```

Now its worked!

Comment: Do not run Composer as root/super user! See https://getcomposer.org/root for details

Answer (score 6):

Run these commands in your terminal.

```
cd storage/
mkdir -p framework/{sessions,views,cache}


chmod -R 775 framework
chown -R www-data:www-data framework
```

Corrected: The folder name 'session' to 'sessions'.
The username can be 'apache'.
You may also need to create the data folder within storage/framework/cache.

Comment: For windows local I did the mkdir with the chmod command and that's it.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

create these folders under **storage/framework**:

- sessions
- views
- cache

Now it should work

Answer (score 1):

Laravel is telling you that is missing the valid cache folder which is located in `storage` then create the following folders

```
sudo mkdir storage/framework
sudo mkdir storage/framework/sessions
sudo mkdir storage/framework/views
sudo mkdir storage/framework/cache
sudo mkdir storage/framework/cache/data
```

So remember to change the permission as follow

```
sudo chmod -R 777 storage
```

After run

```
composer update
```

or run the following command in terminal

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear 
php artisan view:clear
```

Comment: 777 is always a bad idea

Answer (score 0):

After add missing folders do these commands :

1- php artisan config:cache
2 - php artisan cache:clear

These steps work for me