# Please provide a valid cache path Laravel5.7

Tags: php, caching, path, apache2, laravel-5.7

I have two document roots in my laravel project. One project is for web application and another one is for Rest API and Admin backend. My webapplication is working fine but my backend is not working at all. Neither the backend nor api are working.

If i try to open the backend, it says "Please provide a valid cache path". I have gone through different post on google, every one says create folder under storage/framework. I have all the folders like cache, session, view, testing.

Everything seems to be placed fine, but not getting any clue for this error. Please help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel Error: Please provide a valid cache path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38931728/laravel-error-please-provide-a-valid-cache-path)

Comment: Not it did not help. It is also asking to create folders and run composer install. I have already done that many times.

Answer (score 0):

Everything was fine but just required to clear few config, cache. So I just ran through this comments from someone and it helped me solving my issues

I combined this with php artisan cache:clear and php artisan config:clear and php artisan view:clear from the answer below and then it worked

Answer (score 0):

You need to create folders inside "framework". Please Follow these steps:

```
cd storage/
mkdir -p framework/{sessions,views,cache}
```

You also need to set permissions to allow Laravel to write data in this directory.

```
chmod -R 775 framework
chown -R www-data:www-data framework
```